# Why should you check a static variable for nil if it was initialized to nil on the previous line?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Below is a code sample from [Apple's iOS Core Data tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/04_Adding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH106-SW2) and I thought it was weird that the conditional statements are checking if the object is nil. Wouldn't the object always evaluate to nil if the line before the conditional sets the object to nil?

```
// A date formatter for the time stamp
static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
if (dateFormatter == nil) {
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because of the `static`. This variable is not set to `nil` whenever the execution passes through that statement, it 's only set on program startup.

That's a feature of static storage duration variables. They're set to their initialised value at startup and retain whatever value you set them to after that. For example, the following code:

```
void plugh(void) {
    static int xyzzy = 0;
    printf (" %d", xyzzy); // or Obj-C equivalent.
    xyzzy++;
}
```

will not output a long string of zeros if you call it a hundered times. It will output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 ...
```

In th case of the Apple code, it means the date formatter will be created on demand and (unless you set it *back* to `nil` somewhere else) only once. This can someties be important for performance if the object creation is a non trivial thing but, even if not, there's no point in continuously recreating something you can simply re-use.

Comment: Well, actually it would, because you never increment `xyzzy`. Perhaps `printf (# %d", xyzzy++);`?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, I realised that after I pressed the submit button so then fixed it. Not one of the brighter moments of my time here :-)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I actually feel silly I didn't notice the static keyword there, but this is good information nonetheless.

Comment: Tiny question to you "static experts" :) - I met a weird bug relative to a static variable. In the question example, let's say we skip the "= nil" when we declare the static variable. What value would it be set to? Any random value? (in which case, it might compromize the fact that it ever enters the if statement)

Comment: @Dirty, statics should be set to a NULL pointer which I believe is effectively the same as `nil` (different type but same value), at least in Apple's implementation.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming this code is from the body of a function. You need to note that the variable is `static`.  That means yes, the first time this function is called, it will be set to `nil`.  However, the *next* time the function is called, it retains its value from the previous call.

So the result of this is [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).  A new `NSDateFormatter` is initialized only the first time this function is called.

`static` essentially makes it a global variable, initialized to that value, but is visible only to the function it is declared in.

Comment: «a global variable, [...] visible only to the function it is declared in» This is a contradiction. I don't think you mean "global".

Comment: I mean global, in the sense that is is not allocated on the stack, as with most function-local variables.

Comment: Okay, well, that's not what "global" means. Global refers to visibility. You're talking about storage location.

Comment: I understand that, but I thought it made more sense than saying it was in the '.data' section.

Answer (score 1):

The "static" means it only evaluated once, upon initializing that class and on the first run through. Subsequent runs through will skip right over it and continue to the next line.